# Style.css does not change

Tags: html, web, styles

I am having a problem with my style.css I am trying to create a white box be hide the text but it does not update, any help would be helpful.

```css
#advantages{
 text-align: center;
}
#advantages .box {
 background: #ffffff;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages"><!-- advantages Begin -->
  <div class="container"><!-- container Begin -->
   <div class="same-height-row"><!-- same-height-row Begin -->
    <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- col-sm-4 Begin -->
     <div class="box same-height"><!-- box same-height Begin -->
      <div class="icon"><!-- icon Begin -->
       <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
      </div><!-- icon Finished -->
       <h3><a href="#">We Love Our Products</a></h3>
       <p>We know to provide the best posible product ever</p>
     </div><!-- box same-height Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-sm-4 Finished -->
    <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- col-sm-4 Begin -->
     <div class="box same-height"><!-- box same-height Begin -->
      <div class="icon"><!-- icon Begin -->
       <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
      </div><!-- icon Finished -->
       <h3><a href="#">Best Prices</a></h3>
       <p>Compare us with another site, who have the best prices.</p>
     </div><!-- box same-height Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-sm-4 Finished -->
    <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- col-sm-4 Begin -->
     <div class="box same-height"><!-- box same-height Begin -->
      <div class="icon"><!-- icon Begin -->
       <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
      </div><!-- icon Finished -->
       <h3><a href="#">100% Original Products</a></h3>
       <p>We just offer you the best and original products.</p>
     </div><!-- box same-height Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-sm-4 Finished -->
    
   </div><!-- same-height-row Finished -->
  </div><!-- container Finished -->
 </div><!-- advantages Finished -->
```

I want their to be a white box be hide the text but instead nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantages is a class so we use '.' for class and '#' for id, 
so replace

```
    #advantages
```

with

```
   .advantages
```

Comment: Thank you I made a mistake with my advantages I put class instead of id I changed it to id and its all works, thanks for the help.

Comment: vote up my answer if it helped you ... Have a great time !!

Answer (score 0):

```css
   <style>
.advantages{
 text-align: center;
}
.advantages .box {
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="advantages"><!-- advantages Begin -->
  <div class="container"><!-- container Begin -->
   <div class="same-height-row"><!-- same-height-row Begin -->
    <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- col-sm-4 Begin -->
     <div class="box same-height"><!-- box same-height Begin -->
      <div class="icon"><!-- icon Begin -->
       <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
      </div><!-- icon Finished -->
       <h3><a href="#">We Love Our Products</a></h3>
       <p>We know to provide the best posible product ever</p>
     </div><!-- box same-height Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-sm-4 Finished -->
    <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- col-sm-4 Begin -->
     <div class="box same-height"><!-- box same-height Begin -->
      <div class="icon"><!-- icon Begin -->
       <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
      </div><!-- icon Finished -->
       <h3><a href="#">Best Prices</a></h3>
       <p>Compare us with another site, who have the best prices.</p>
     </div><!-- box same-height Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-sm-4 Finished -->
    <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- col-sm-4 Begin -->
     <div class="box same-height"><!-- box same-height Begin -->
      <div class="icon"><!-- icon Begin -->
       <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
      </div><!-- icon Finished -->
       <h3><a href="#">100% Original Products</a></h3>
       <p>We just offer you the best and original products.</p>
     </div><!-- box same-height Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-sm-4 Finished -->
    
   </div><!-- same-height-row Finished -->
  </div><!-- container Finished -->
 </div><!-- advantages Finished -->
```

Comment: Can you add a short description to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try following css....

```
.advantages{
    text-align: center;
}
.advantages .box {
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```